# iCloud NSMetadata query results are blank

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, icloud

I've been working on adding [icloud](/questions/tagged/icloud) to my project (which is quite a pain in the buns) and I'm able to save and remove files, but I can't get a list of the files stored in iCloud. I've tried solutions from about 10 different websites (including the Apple documentation). Whenever I call `[self.query startQuery];` everything seems to be working: The correct methods get called, the methods execute exactly as they should. Then when I ask for an [nsarray](/questions/tagged/nsarray) of the files in my app's iCloud Documents directory I get two parenthesis with nothing between them (when I view in NSLog): `File List: ( )`. I know for a fact that there are many different documents of all shapes, extensions, sizes, and names in my app's iCloud Documents directory because I've been using the [iCloud Developer](https://developer.icloud.com) site to check if things are working. My first method to setup the query is as follows:

```
- (void)syncWithCloud {
self.query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
NSURL *mobileDocumentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
[query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, nil]];
//[query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
[query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%K like \"%@*\"", [mobileDocumentsDirectoryURL path]], NSMetadataItemPathKey]];

//Pull a list of all the Documents in The Cloud
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(processFiles:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:self.query];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(processFiles:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:self.query];

[self.query startQuery];
}
```

The [process files method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101/SearchingforiCloudDocuments/SearchingforiCloudDocuments.html) provided by Apple is next:

```
- (void)processFiles:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSMutableArray *discoveredFiles = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Always disable updates while processing results.
    [query disableUpdates];

    //The query reports all files found, every time.
    NSArray *queryResults = [query results];
    for (NSMetadataItem *result in queryResults) {
        NSURL *fileURL = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSNumber *aBool = nil;

        // Don't include hidden files.
        [fileURL getResourceValue:&aBool forKey:NSURLIsHiddenKey error:nil];
        if (aBool && ![aBool boolValue])
            [discoveredFiles addObject:fileURL];
    }

    //Update the list of documents.
    [FileList removeAllObjects];
    [FileList addObjectsFromArray:discoveredFiles];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];

    //Reenable query updates.
    [query enableUpdates];

    NSLog(@"File List: %@", FileList);
}
```

Why doesn't this give me a list of files or at least some kind of data? Am I defining the NSMetadata query wrong, maybe my predicate isn't formatted right? I know I'm doing something wrong because there's no way iCloud could be this complicated (or could it?).
Thanks for the help in advance!

**Edit** #1: I am continuing to try different approaches to this problem. Using one of the answers below I have changed the predicate filter as follows:

```
[query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NSMetadataItemFSNameKey LIKE '*'"]];
```

I have also added the following lines *before* the `[query enableUpdates]` call:

```
for (NSMetadataItem *item in query.results) {
        [FileList addObject:[item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
 }
```

In the `processFiles` method, I've tried placing all of the code on the background thread, but this makes no difference - as a matter of fact, when the code is not executed on the background thread `FileList` gives me this `(null)` instead of this `( )`.

**Could my problem have to do with thread management or memory allocation?** Please note that I am using ARC.

**Edit** #2: The `FileList` variable is an NSMutableArray defined in my `@interface` and initialized in the `-(id)init` method before calling the `processFiles` method.

**Edit** #3: When testing my code with breakpoints I found that the following [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) never gets run through - not even once. This leads me to believe that:
  A. The proper directory isn't being connected with
  B. iCloud can't see the files in the directory
  C. My NSMetadataQuery isn't being setup properly
  D. Something completely different

Here's the code that starts the for-loop which never gets run:

```
NSArray *queryResults = [query results];
for (NSMetadataItem *result in queryResults) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Getting the list of files in iCloud was just a matter of correctly defining, allocating, and initializing properties. **SAE**'s answer and this [SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950804/nsmetadataquery-doesnt-find-icloud-files) helped me solve my problem and create this GitHub Repo called [iCloud Document Sync](https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync). The iCloud Document Sync class simplifies the whole iCloud Document storage process down to a few lines of code. The commit linked [here](https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync/commit/98524196401920d75a0e5d7c506661ca825863c5) fixes the issues from my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already set the search scope correct, there's no need to use special filters in the predicate.
Just use:

```
query.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NSMetadataItemFSNameKey == '*'"];
```

And to get the array use:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSMetadataItem *item in query.results) {
        [array addObject:[item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
}
```

Comment: I'm still not getting any results with this. I've even tried moving the process off of the background queue, but all that does is make the result `(null` instead of `( )`. Suggestions? Is it possible that my `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier` is not setup correctly?

Comment: You don't need the NSURL above and therefore you don't the ContainerIdentifier. Have a look at the [sample code](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook/tree/master/C18/02-UIDocument) from Erica Sadun's fine iOS cookbook. You'll want to examine the CloudHelper class.

Comment: What exactly is `FileList`? From the naming convention it reads like a class, not like an object or variable.

Comment: FileList is defined in the @interface section of my class like this: `NSMutableArray *FileList;`. And thanks for the link!

Comment: And is FileList properly initialized before it is used in processFiles?

Comment: It is initialized in the `-(id)init` method (which is getting called, I checked with breakpoints) like this: `FileList = [NSMutableArray array];`. I also tried it like this: `FileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, but still it didn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22012/discussion-between-razorsharp-and-sae)

Comment: Can you please share any predicate which can give us all iCloud Drive data either it is img , pdf or text files.